# NodeJS with ReactJS + React-Router-Dom works incorrect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an app using ReactJS + ReactRouterDom.

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

import IndexPage      from './pages/IndexPage';
import LoginPage      from './pages/LoginPage';
import ContactsPage   from './pages/ContactsPage';
import AboutPage      from './pages/AboutPage';

function App() {
  return (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
            <IndexPage />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/about">
            <AboutPage />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/about/story">
            <AboutPage />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/login">
            <LoginPage />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/contacts">
            <ContactsPage />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

Main problem is, when i run app using **yarn start** everything is works fine.

When am trying to run with **express**, is shown 404 error any page but index

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('public/index.html'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

> Thanks for answer!

Comment: are you trying to create a react front end and nodejs +express backend ?

Comment: because react dosen't routes with expressjs. Expressjs is for backend Route management.

Comment: Yes. I'm using NodeJS as Backend for ReactJS app. Is normal practice in the world @ZunaibImtiaz

Comment: Follow this then https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/full-stack-mongodb-react-node-js-express-js-in-one-simple-app-6cc8ed6de274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On express server code, You also have to handle other pages.

Your current code will be working for other pages when you redirect from the app but you will be getting 404 when directly hitting URL from the browser.

Try adding/handling `*` url in express server and render `index.js` in it.  It will catch all urls and render the same react page for them.  You can handle `404` within React router

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.render('public/index.html')
})
```

Comment: It was a problem with express static, i should use 

express()
  .use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

i fogot '/public'

Comment: i recive: Error: Cannot find module 'html' using it